# What does ipg/ewma mean in an output of ping -f?

Tags: networking, ping

I pinged in a flood mode:

```
# ping -c 1000000 -f 127.0.0.1
```

and I got the following output:

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1000000 packets transmitted, 1000000 received, 0% packet loss, time 15408ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.003/0.004/0.798/0.003 ms, ipg/ewma 0.015/0.005 ms
```

I found nothing in `man ping` about this, but I found an article about [IPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpacket_gap). After reading it, I understand that the lower value is better.

What then means the EWMA value, its lower and higher value or the ratio of IGP and EWMA? What causes changes in the IGP and EWMA values?

Answer (score 4):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average

It stands for Exponential Weight Moving Average.  It's a way of using a continuously-functioning output (say a long-running fping/ping -f) to get more-relevant results.  For a long-running ping, all old values no matter how old are still used for computing the min/max/avg but the use of EWMA gives you more relevant results for more recent pings.

Comment: Could you also explain what IPG means in this output?